# Recursão e soma

Tags: c, funções, recursão, array

Estou fazendo um programa no qual necessita uma recursão de acordo com o exercício que faça a soma de um vetor de duas matrizes e soma as linhas após a recursão e depois some as colunas seguem o meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int recursion(int array[3]){

    int i  = 1;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){

        if(i == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        else if(array == 1){
            return 1;
        }

        return recursion(array[i]+array[i+1]);
        printf("%d",array[i]);
    }
}



int main ( ) {
    int array[3][3];
    int arraytemp[3];

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
        arraytemp[j]=0;
        for(j=0;j<=3;j++){
            scanf("%d", & array[i][j]);
            arraytemp[j]=array[j];
        }
        recursion(arraytemp);    
    }
}
```

Comment: não entendi exatamente o que você quer, tem como passar o exercício que você disse (enunciado).

Comment: O *header* `<conio.h>` não é Standard. Não usas nada que esteja lá definido. Tiro-o dos teus includes.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int recursion(int array[3]){

    int i  = 1;                                // ==> nota a)

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){                          // ==> nota a)

        if(i == 0){                            // ==> nota b)
            return 0;
        }
        else if(array == 1){                   // ==> nota c)
            return 1;
        }

        return recursion(array[i]+array[i+1]); // ==> nota d)
        printf("%d",array[i]);                 // ==> nota e)
    }
}



int main ( ) {
    int array[3][3];
    int arraytemp[3];

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<=3;i++){                         // ==> nota f)
        arraytemp[j]=0;                        // ==> nota g)
        for(j=0;j<=3;j++){                     // ==> nota f) outra vez
            scanf("%d", & array[i][j]);
            arraytemp[j]=array[j];             // ==> nota h)
        }
        recursion(arraytemp);    
    }
}                                              // ==> nota i)
```

Notas:

a) Primeiro metes `i` a `1` e logo logo a seguir metes a `0`. Não necessitas da primeira atribuição.

b) A primeira vez que o ciclo é executado, o valoe de `i` vai ser `0` (é o que está no `for`). Portanto a primeira coisa que o ciclo faz é termninar a função com o `return` desta instrução.

c) O programa nunca aqui chega (ver nota b)). Se chegasse iria comparar um array (o array com nome `array`) com um inteiro. Arrays e inteiros não são comparaveis! Tens que estar com mais atenção às coisas que comparas.

d) O programa nunca aqui chega (ver nota b))... A função `recursion()` está definida como aceitando um parametro de tipo array. O parametro `array[i] + array[i + 1]` é de tipo `int` que não é compativel com o tipo esperado pela função. Mais uma vez: tens que estar com atenção ao tipo das variáveis. O `return` faz com que a função termine.

e) O programa nunca aqui chega (ver nota b) e nota d))...

f) com `for (i = 0 ; i <= 3; i++) { /* ... */ }` o ciclo será executado 4 vezes. A forma normal dum `for` é primeiro uma atribuição, depois uma comparação com `<` (não `<=`) e finalmente o incremento. Quando se vê uma forma diferente é logo para desconfiar que algo está mal. A versão normal do teu ciclo seria `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { /* ... */ }`.

g) Porquê `j`? ???? A variável `j` ainda não foi atribuido nenhum valor. Não a podes usar como índice dum array.

h) `arraytemp[j]` tem tipo `int`; `array[j]` tem tipo array de 3 int. Não podes atribuir um array a um objecto de tipo `int`. Atenção aos tipos dos objectos que usas

i) Liga o máximo de *warnings* do teu compilador. Está com atenção a esses warnings.

*Happy Coding*